# Add to extra div to the side of the content

Tags: template

I've read some post for adding extra divs to the both sides of the main content and act like a sidebars. But I want to add 2 extra div for adding some graphics and the right will be to the right of the actual sidebar. I took a screenshot for explain my self better.
I've added to extra div before the pagewrap and working with css I locate the divs to left and to the right but there is a problem, if some has a resolution smaller then me the divs start moving messing up the loyout. I want that they stay near the content and the sidebar for all the resolution. I've tryed working with css with position and % but with no results.

Ok so, the cyan rectangle would be the extra divs, and the gray graphics the contents of these. I don't care if the users has smaller resolutions, the graphics can go out the screen, but the "roots" must be fixed to the side of the main content ;)
Hope I explained well.

This is the screenshot
http://cl.ly/0D2H1s0t3Y0p2A412L35/Schermata-2011-01-11-a-22.22.17.png
Thanks for help

Comment: HTML/CSS questions really belong on [Doctype](http://doctype.com)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just place your graphics as [background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) image and center so it aligns with your content?

Comment: 'cause I will have the same problem for other graphics resolution, isn't it?

Comment: @Kreker if you center background properly it won't move around because of resolution. This is very common practice.

Comment: you would have problems with resolution if you would use divs for this